# Creating a text channel without ctx

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to create a mod mail bot, but I've run into a problem where I can't create a ticket channel because I don't have ctx in scope.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message, ctx): # doesn't recieve ctx
  if not message.guild and message.author != bot.user: 
    if message == "!close":
      await message.channel.send("ticket closed")
      return

    await message.channel.send("ticket opened")
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, id=980855086567788564)
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"{message.author}'s ticket", category=category)
```

Comment: Just use `message.guild`, like you already do in the first line of your function.

Answer (score 0):

The `on_message` event does not receive a `ctx` parameter, only `message`. However, `message` can access many of the attributes found in `ctx`. In your case, you can just use `message.guild`.

```py
category = discord.utils.get(message.guild.categories, id=980855086567788564)
await message.guild.create_text_channel(f"{message.author}'s Ticket", category=category)
```